# Create a Virtual IP not attached to any resource in Azure

Tags: azure-networking

I have 2 vm's in Azure running Ensemble.  In Ensemble I can create a mirror for those 2 servers but Ensemble requires a virtual IP for this to work.
How can i add a virtual IP in azure that I can then use for this mirror?

Answer (score 0):

Gratuitous ARP or ND is not allowed in most clouds, which prevents the use of VIPs like this. Floating IPs are not a thing, they are assigned to VMs or other objects.

Also, if your VMs are in different regions, bridging layer 2 is discouraged.

VIP is not required for business continuity of Ensemble (or [Caché](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GHA_mirror_set_virtualip)). Change DNS, put these behind a load balancer, or both.

As evidence this is a consideration for any application on an Azure network, note that [MS SQL clusters also cannot get a VIP in Azure](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6971#issuecomment-382168922).